Optimizing a Complex Project-Employee Assignment Function (Pure nonlinear 0-1 programming)
I'm working on optimizing a project-employee assignment problem involving a complex objective function. I'm seeking help to understand the best approach to maximizing this function.
The objective function is as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    &\text{max}\sum_{i=1}^M E_i \\
    &= \text{max}\sum_{i=1}^M \left[\hat{W_i} + \frac{\sum_{j \neq i} \left[ (W_i - \hat{W_i}) \cdot C_{ij} \cdot A_j \right]}{\sum_{j=1}^M C_{ij}}\right] \\
    &= \text{max}\sum_{i=1}^M \left[W_i \cdot \log_2(1 + A_i) + \frac{\sum_{j \neq i} \left[ (W_i - W_i \cdot \log_2(1 + A_i)) \cdot C_{ij} \cdot A_j \right]}{\sum_{j=1}^M C_{ij}}\right] \\
    &= \text{max}\sum_{i=1}^M \left[ W_i \cdot \log_2(1 + A_i) + \frac{W_i \cdot [1 - \log_2(1 + A_i)]\sum_{j \neq i}C_{ij} \cdot A_j}{\sum_{j=1}^M C_{ij}}\right] \\
    &= \text{max}\sum_{i=1}^M W_i \left[\log_2\left(1 + \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N S_k \cdot x_{i,k}}{\sum_{k=1}^N x_{i,k}}\right) + \frac{\left[1 - \log_2\left(1 + \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N S_k \cdot x_{i,k}}{\sum_{k=1}^N x_{i,k}}\right)\right]\sum_{j \neq i}C_{ij} \cdot \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N S_k \cdot x_{j,k}}{\sum_{k=1}^N x_{j,k}}}{\sum_{j=1}^M C_{ij}}\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Where:
$M$ is the number of projects
$N$ is the number of employees
$W_i$ is the importance of project $i$
$C_{ij}$ is the collaboration coefficient between projects $i$ and $j$
$S_k$ is the skill level of employee $k$
$x_{i,k}$ is a binary variable indicating whether employee $k$ is assigned to project $i$
$A_i = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N s_k \cdot x_{i,k}}{\sum_{k=1}^N x_{i,k}}$ represents the average skill level of employees assigned to project $i$
Subject to the following constraints:
The number of employees is greater than the number of projects: $N > M$
Each employee can only be assigned to one project: $\sum_{i=1}^M x_{i,k} = 1, \forall k \in {1,\ldots,N}$
Each project can be assigned multiple employees: $\sum_{k=1}^N x_{i,k} \geq 0, \forall i \in {1,\ldots,M}$
Binary constraint: $x_{i,k} \in \{0,1\}, \forall i \in {1,\ldots,M}, \forall k \in {1,\ldots,N}$
My understanding of the problem:
This is a nonlinear 0-1 programming problem. Projects are ranked by importance, and employees are ranked by their skill levels. There are correlations between projects, and the progress of one project can influence others based on these correlations. The only variables in this problem are in the assignment matrix. Both $x_{i,k}$ and $x_{j,k}$ jointly form the final assignment matrix, but they also influence each other because each employee can only be assigned to one project. Currently, I'm attempting to iteratively optimize these two variables to obtain the final assignment matrix.
I'm particularly interested in:
Solve this problem numerically. Understand if this function can be linearized or transformed into a more tractable form. Explore potential optimization techniques suitable for this type of problem.
Any insights or suggestions on how to approach this optimization problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
